# Variables PHP y AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy con una duda espero puedan ayudarme

```
  $('#add_return1').click(function () {

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'anular.php',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

Tengo este código que se activa con un `button`, dentro del archivo `anular.php` tengo variables que están declaradas dentro del archivo principal.

Mi duda es como hago para que estas variables también se carguen.

Es decir en el archivo principal tengo por ejemplo declarado

`$numero = 2;`

En el archivo anular se encuentran funciones basadas en `$numero` pero no funcionan.

Espero su ayuda.

Comment: Quizá en 'anular.php' has un include con el archivo principal, ej: 
include "principal.php"

Comment: La pregunta es que no sabes acceder a las variables que envias?

Comment: realiza un echo $numero;

Comment: O podrías mostrarnos tu código en anular.php ?

Comment: Es obvio, cuando llamas a anular.php se evaluan esas variables y como no estan declaradas (que las declares en el principal no sirve de nada pues este no se ejecuta al ejecutar anular.php) valen NULL. Creo que aún no has comprendido del todo como funciona PHP.